# SAS: How to include Zeros or Missing Values when calculating Median, Minimum and Maximum?

Tags: sas, mean, zero, proc, proc-sql

I am trying to calculate median, minimum and maximum for several variables for last 5 years in Base SAS. Some of the variables had no cases of diseases in some years, so 0 cases. When I calculate summary in SAS, I want to include these zeros.

For example: one of my variable, lets say X, had 8, 6, 2, 0, 0 cases in the last 5 years respectively. When I calculate the summary of this variable either using "proc-sql" or "proc-means", SAS is ignoring those 0's and giving me something different than what I am expecting. I would like to get Min=0, Max=8 and Median=2, but SAS is giving me Min=2, Max=8 and Median=6 as it is ignoring the zeros.

Any suggestion or direction would be appreciated?

Comment: if min is 0 then you will have zero. you mean say that your did not have any values for that year/month. can you please provide a sample dataset and sample output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly have missing data you can replace those with zeroes using PROC STDIZE (assuming you have SAS/STAT).

```
proc stdize data=have out=want replace; run;
```

Comment: I have replaced the missing data with 0's in the data step by adding: 
Options missing='0';

I want to include these 0's when calculating the summary. As I mentioned in the question, I want the minimum to be 0 rather than 2 that SAS is giving me as it is not including those zeros when calculating the summary statistics.

Answer (score 0):

SAS will include 0, it will not include missing. You possibly have a format on top of your variable that is showing it as 0 when it's actually missing. 
Try removing the format and see if that's the case, otherwise, this is the default behaviour of SAS.

You can remove formats using:

```
format var; *note lack of format, which removes the format;
```

Or if you set `option missing` to 0 then it shows missing as 0, but the underlying value is still missing and will not be included. You need to actually change the values to 0.

Comment: I had replaced the missing data with 0's in the data step by adding: Options missing='0';

Is there a way to make SAS calculate median(8, 6, 2, 0, 0) and give 2 as the result instead of 6? It is giving 6 because it is ignoring those 0's. Same was minimum(8, 6, 2, 0, 0) = 0 instead of 2.

Comment: Options Missing does not replace anything, it simply shows as 0, similar to how a format works. The underlying data is still missing and will not be included.

Comment: That explains why SAS is not outputting what I was expecting. Can you please suggest a way to replace the missing values with zeros? I have several columns/variables that have missing values and I would like to replace them with 0's to calculate the summary statistics. Would a simple if statement work in this case?

Comment: @TivosJar did you not try the solution from Craig below? It works to replace all numeric to 0. If you want specific variables, you can list them though. Otherwise, if it's more complicated, yes an IF statement will work fine.

Comment: I did try the solution Craig suggested. However, I get an warning message "WARNING: The scale estimator for variable XYZ is less than or equal to 0. Variable XYZ will not be standardized and a missing value is assigned to its scale estimator."

It also changed all the non-missing whole numbers to decimals. I only want to replace the missing values to 0's not standardize the whole data set. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `non-missing whole numbers to decimals` I think it just changed the format, not the value. SAS only has two types, numeric/character.